# How to retrieve or update data inside Doctrine lifecycle events listener

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony4

In a Symfony4.4-based application, inside preUpdate() method of my event listener, I'm just trying to query an entity data from database using classic and known Symfony code to do so, for the sake of testing: `$entity = $entityManager->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->find($entity->getId());`. In fact, I'm using the following entry point to send the request `PUT /api/update-my-entity` using Postman as API client, with the following input in which I'm editing only company id value:

```
{
    "id":"6532",
    "licenseValue":"AABBTT",
    "company":30,
    "type":"E145",
    "deleteAutorized":true,
    "editedBy":"admin"
}
```

Instead of returning $entity data from database, I'm getting the input data as $entity value.

So, I want to know from which callback method can one interact with database inside a doctrine event listener to retrieve or update database?

Many thanks in advance for helping out.

UPDATE :
This is what I'm testing in the preUpdate() function:

```
    /**
     * @param MyEntity $entity
     * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs
     * @return void
     */
    public function preUpdate(MyEntity $myEntity, PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {

        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if (!$entity instanceof MyEntity) {
            return;
        }
        $entityManager = $eventArgs->getObjectManager();
        /**@var MyEntity */
        $myEntity = $entityManager->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->find($myEntity->getId());
        dump($entity->getId());
        dump($myEntity->getId()); // returns input value instead of database value
        dump($myEntity->getLicenseValue()); // returns input value
        dump($myEntity->getCompany()->getId()); // returns input value
        die("Ok");
    }
```

Comment: Might help to see the code in the preUpdate function. Use of `PreUpdateEventArgs`? Think back in Doctrine 2.x days it would be through `getUnitOfWork`?

Comment: @ficuscr, I've just updated my post to add the content of preUpdate() method